# How to I add push data to an array in Mongoose DB on create method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to initialize my Mongoose Schema with objects in the array in my create method.

My Schema looks like the following:

```
var imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    url: {type:String},
    text: {type:String}
});

module.exports = todo.model('Todo', new mongoose.Schema ({
    name : {type : String, default: ''},
    dataArr : [imageSchema]
}));
```

And my route looks like:

```
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

    Todo.create({
        name : req.body.name,
    },

    { $push : { dataArr : {  url : 'foo' , text : 'bar'} } },

    function(err, todo) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the create method doesn't accept a second parameter where you can provide the $push.

Since you are creating the object, just set the array naively:

```
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

    Todo.create({
        name : req.body.name,
        dataArr : [{  url : 'foo' , text : 'bar'}] 
    }, 
    function(err, todo) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as an array to the object that is used to create the model instance:

```
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {
  Todo.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    dataArr: [{url: 'foo', text: 'bar'}]
  }, function(err, todo) {
    if (err) { res.send(err); }
  });
});
```